# Grep files excluding few files names

Tags: linux, grep

I have a folder who have files names according to date for one month i.e. AP_20140101.gz, AP_20140102.gz, ... for each day. Here 2014 is year, 01 is month and 01 is date (AP_YYYYMMDD.gz is general format )

For selecting files for date 10 to 19 I can do this :

```
ls | grep *2014011*
```

But I am unable to grep from 15 to 31. Any suggestions?

Comment: By the way, you never need to `grep '*foo*'` that is exactly the same as `grep foo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't need grep to do the work, your shell should be able to do it. If you're using bash then you could try using ranges

```
ls AP_201401{15..31}.gz
```

seems to work.

If any of the files don't exist then you will get an error message so you may need to pipe stderr to a file.

Comment: Excellent !! Simple and Effective.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing shell wildcards (like the pattern you typed) with regular expressions (which grep expects).  A regular expression to do what you want with grep would be

```
ls | grep '201401(1[5-9]|2|3)'
```

The shell wildcard expression in bash would be

```
ls *201401{1{5..9},2,3}*
```

Please read about shell wildcards in the EXPANSION section in `man bash`, and regular expressions in `man grep` or `man 7 regex`.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` patterns are regular expressions, and '*2014011*' isn't doing what you think it is. Take some time to [learn the basics](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) if you don't understand why. Hint: '*' doesn't just match any character.

In this case simple wildcards will work perfectly well without `grep`, so you could simply do this:

```
ls *2014011*
```

For more info, you can read about [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html). Link is for bash, which I assume you are using.

Answer (score 0):

@Iian gave the perfect answer. 
BTW you can also use 'find' command as well.

> find . -type f -name 'AP_201401[15-31].gz'